# How do I properly use a split in Java

Tags: java

I've been doing this code but I've been stuck on how to properly split a text file. How would I be able to do this? I am using a two dimensional array, whilst reading from a text file.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    int entry;
    String hockeyStats[][] = new String[8][30];//Array initialized, up to 30 players in total can be in the database.
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Vancouver Stats.txt"));//Text file with player names imported.
    // FULL NAME, GOALS, ASSISTS, PLUSMINUS, PENALTY MINUTES, SHOTS
    String listnumbers="word";
    while (listnumbers!=null)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<30;++x)
        {
            listnumbers=input.readLine();
            String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" ");
            for (int y=0; y<7;++y)
            {
                hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];
            }

        }
    }
    input.close();
```

What must I do? I don't understand the problem here. Here is what is inside my text file, Vancouver Stats

```
Kesler Ryan 22 27 11 56 222
Sedin Henrik 14 67 23 52 113  
Edler Alexander 11 38 0 34 228 
Hansen Jannik 16 23 18 34 137 
Hamhuis Dan 4 33 29 46 140  
Tanev Christopher 0 2 10 2 15
```

I am confused at how to get these sets of data and put them into a 2D array so that I can then ask the user if they want to sort, search for players, add them, etc.

Please and thanks if anyone could help me!

Comment: Actually, it would be better and more logical to put data in an _Array_ of objects that represent player

Comment: you're inserting your data backwards.  You have your array be 8 row, 30 columns, but when you go to iterate over it and inserting your going column-row.  Your sizes won't match and your program will crash.  This is why we use things like yourArray.length and yourArray[0].length instead of hardcoded values for iterative loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your test file and manage your data using following piece of code.

```
 try {
            File file=new File("asd.txt");
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);
            /*
             * If Players name are unique
             */
            Map<String,ArrayList> mPlayerData=new HashMap();
            ArrayList mData=new ArrayList();

            while(sc.hasNext()){
                 String mPlayerName="";
                 Scanner sc2=new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
                 sc2.useDelimiter(" ");
                 int i=0;
                 while(sc2.hasNext()){
                     if(i<2){
                         mPlayerName=mPlayerName.equalsIgnoreCase("")?sc2.next():mPlayerName+" "+sc2.next();
                     }else{
                         mData.add(sc2.next());
                     }
                     i++;
                 }
                 mPlayerData.put(mPlayerName, mData);
            }
            System.err.println(mPlayerData.size());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Enjoy......

Answer (score 0):

here's the problem that occurs to me.

```
String hockeyStats[][] = new String[8][30];
```

You appear to have your dimensions backward here, considering later you refer to is as:

```
hockeyStats[x][y]
```

Where you iterate over 30 players in `x`, and 8 attributes in `y`.  You should declare your stats array `new String[30][8]`.  If the problem was an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, that ought to solve it.

---

```
String listnumbers="word";
//Here, we check for a null value.  Two reasons this isn't working, see the following comments.
while (listnumbers!=null)
{
    //Looping through 30 records, without ever touching the while loop.
    //This attempts to read and add 30 lines, then checks whether listnumbers is null
    //(and if not, adds another 30, etc.)
    for (int x=0; x<30;++x)
    {
        //You might get listnumbers == null here
        listnumbers=input.readLine();
        //And if you do, it will throw an exception here!
        //Note, there is nothing checking for null between those two points.
        String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" ");
        for (int y=0; y<7;++y)
        {
            hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];
        }

    }
}
```

There are a couple of alternatives you could use.  One is, get rid of the while loop, and do this instead:

```
for (int x=0; x<30;++x)
{
    listnumbers=input.readLine();
    if (listnumbers == null) break;
    String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" ");
    for (int y=0; y<7;++y)
    {
        hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it was based in rows and columns? ARRAY[rows][columns]? I have that set, but now it gives me an error with 

String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" "); 

being null?

Comment: You can think about it as rows and columns, but in that case, you declared it to have [rows = 8][columns = 30], which is still backwards.

Comment: Okay, sure it does.  You have a couple of problems with how you iterate the list, now that I'm looking at it a bit more closely.  I'll update my answer with some comments on that.

Comment: what if temp have length < 8 in hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];? error, out of bound,

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  If you can't count on every record having 8 (or more) values, that would have to be handled.  This could be fairly easily handled by changing the exit condition of the inner for loop to: `y<Math.min(7,temp.length)`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a working code for your problem. The code is as below. I will try to explain some of the things you implemented wrong.

1. `hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];` gets outs of bound exception because `x` advances past 8. Remember `hockeyStats` is of size 8x30
2. `String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" ")` hits null exception because `listnumbers=input.readLine();` may have not read any input. this happens at the end of the file.

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;

   ```
   public class vvvd {

   public static void main(String[] ards ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
   //Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
   int entry;
   String hockeyStats[][] = new String[8][30];//Array initialized, up to 30 players in total can be in the database.
   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Vancouver.txt"));//Text file with player names imported.
   // FULL NAME, GOALS, ASSISTS, PLUSMINUS, PENALTY MINUTES, SHOTS
   String listnumbers="word";

   listnumbers=input.readLine();
   int x = 0;
   while (listnumbers!=null)
   {
       //for (int x=0; x<8;++x)
       //{

         if(x >= 8)
             break;

           String temp[]=listnumbers.split(" ");
           for (int y=0; y<7;++y)
           {
               hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];
           }

       //}
     x++;
    listnumbers=input.readLine();
   }
   input.close();
   ```

   }

Comment: what if temp have length < 8 in hockeyStats[x][y]=temp[y];? error, out of bound,

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of maintainability, what we could do to simplify things is create a helpful struct-like class for your stat holders.

```
static class HockeyPlayer extends Comparable<HockeyPlayer>
{
    static final int VALUES_LENGTH = 5;  //we like knowing how many stats we should be handling
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    int[] values;

    /**
     * Creates a data structure holding player data of hockey stats
     * @throws FormatException 
     *     when the data passed in does not have enough values stored or if 
     *     the stats could not be parsed into integers
     */
    public HockeyPlayer(String data) throws FormatException
    {
        String[] parsedData = data.split();
        if (data.length != 2 + VALUES_LENGTH)
        {
            throw new FormatException();
        }
        lastName = parsedData[0];
        firstName = parsedData[1];
        values = new int[VALUES_LENGTH]
        // we use two counters, one for the parsed data index and 
        // another for the values index
        for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < values.length; i++, j++)
        {
            //make sure the numbers are parsed into int
            values[i] = Integer.parseInt(parsedData[j]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comparison handling method of Comparable objects.  
     * Very useful in sorting
     * @return 0 when equal, -1 when less than, 1 when greater than
     */
    public int compareTo(HockeyPlayer player2)
    {
       //I'll leave this for you to set up since you know how you want your values organized
       return 0;
    }
}
```

A class formatted like this can be very helpful for a large amount of reasons.  First, if a line is formatted improperly, instead of breaking your program you can catch the error more easily than doing tons of if-statements because it gives you an exception the explicitly says the line was formatted wrong.  On top of that, it implements the Comparable class, with a data type of HockeyPlayer as what it can compare against.  If you put your data into an `ArrayList<HockeyPlayer>`, you can easily add new players, as well as sort with `Collections.sort()`.

You'd have to add your own methods for searching by specific parameters such as name or some stat, but assembling the array is a whole lot easier now.

```
ArrayList<HockeyPlayer> list = new ArrayList<HockeyPlayer>();

while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    String data = input.nextLine();
    try
    {
       HockeyPlayer player = new HockeyPlayer(data);
       list.add(player);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
       System.err.println("Player data not formatted correctly");
    }
}
```

I always find it truly amazing how much nicer your program can become with the introduction of a few structs.

Comment: Wow, I have never seen this before. What are these structs you add with ArrayList and so?

Comment: @BobbyOres sorry about the really late response.  ArrayLists allow you to use type assignment to the kinds of contents that can be managed by it.  You can implement it into any of your classes that you make as well.  They're called Generics, or occasionally you'll see them referred to as Templates